# Как сделать верстку станицы с закрашенными блоками в шахматном порядке?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть вот такая верстка, это таблица в которой ячейки раскрашенные в шахматном порядке. Все бы ничего, но мне надо первую ячейку сделать `rowspan="2"`. Когда я так делаю то вся таблица сдвигается, пробовал удалять соседнюю ячейку, но потом цвета сбиваются. Подскажите как это реализовать?

как это должно выглядеть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
 
}
.container{
 width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.shahmatka{
 background-color: #eefaf9;
}
td{
 width: 168px;
 height: 168px;
}

/*вот так сделал шахматную доску :) */
tr:first-child td:nth-child(odd){
 border: 1px solid #44c3be;
 background: #0cb1aa;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(even){
 border: 1px solid #a7e3e0;
 background: #0cb1aa;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(odd){
 border: 1px solid #44c3be;
 background: #0cb1aa;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="shahmatka">
   <tr>
    <td><p>Блоки обучения</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>АРТ</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>СПОРТ</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>STEM</p></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>Гуманитарный блок</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>ІТ</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>МЕДИА</p></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><p>PERFOMANS</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>ПОЛИГЛОТ</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>БИЗНЕС</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>СОЦИАЛЬНАЯ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬ</p></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавь `colspan=2` к этой ячейке и удали следующую за ней ячейку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что - то такое?

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
 
}
.container{
 width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.shahmatka{
 background-color: #eefaf9;
}
td{
 width: 168px;
 height: 168px;
}

/*вот так сделал шахматную доску :) */
tr:first-child td:nth-child(odd){
 border: 1px solid #44c3be;
 background: #0cb1aa;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(even){
 border: 1px solid #a7e3e0;
 background: #0cb1aa;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(odd){
 border: 1px solid #44c3be;
 background: #0cb1aa;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="shahmatka">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>Блоки обучения</p></td>
        <td style="display:none;"></td>
    <td><p>АРТ</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>СПОРТ</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>STEM</p></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>Гуманитарный блок</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>ІТ</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>МЕДИА</p></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><p>PERFOMANS</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>ПОЛИГЛОТ</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>БИЗНЕС</p></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>СОЦИАЛЬНАЯ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬ</p></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Странно у вас работает, а я только что поправил у себя, и у меня опять сбивается

Comment: А теперь работает?

Comment: да, работает спасибо!